# How to solve problems with AppxPackaging.dll (Windows App Certification Kit)?

Tags: windows, dll, library, sdk

We receive the follow error message on building an UWP application.

> Task 'ValidateAppxManifest' failed. Retrieving the COM class factory
>   for component with CLSID {5842A140-FF9F-4166-8F5C-62F5B7B0C781} failed
>   due to the following error: 8007045a A dynamic link library (DLL)
>   initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A).

{5842A140-FF9F-4166-8F5C-62F5B7B0C781} pointed to AppxPackaging.dll. The registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{5842a140-ff9f-4166-8f5c-62f5b7b0c781}\InProcServer32` exists.

The build system is a docker with Windows Server Core and Visual Studio 2017.

How can I receive more information over the underlying problem?

Which components must be installed that the "Windows App Certification Kit" is work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppxPackaging is part of the `Windows Kits` installation of the SDK. The error hints at a missing dependency.

We used `procmon` (eg. `choco install procmon`) to try to find out which dependency that was. You have to set a filter in `Path contains Appx` and run the build job.

**Note:** if the build job runs in a Docker Container as you described you have to run `procmon` on the host, not the container.

The process list filled up with a lot of information up to the point the `AppxPackaging.dll` is loaded. It then stated, that a `AppxSip.dll` was looked up at the `Path` destinations, but was not found (Result: `NAME NOT FOUND`). So we checked the system for this dll.

We did find a corresponding file in the Windows Kits subfolder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86` and added this path the the `$env:Path` environment. Then it worked out.